# How do I interpret Feynman diagrams when the expansion parameter is a tensor that depends on the momentum?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, condensed-matter, perturbation-theory, spin-models

I've read through chapter 5 of Atland & Simons about five times and I feel like I understand everything in the chapter, but it only covers the case where the expansion parameter is a constant whereas I'm interested in the case where the expansion parameter is a tensor that depends on momentum. In particular I'm trying to understand this in the context of spin wave theory, such as is presented in [this paper](https://journals.aps.org/prx/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevX.8.011010) (particularly the diagrams in figure 1d).

I have a similar Hamiltonian where the perturbation looks something like
$$
H^{(4)} = \sum_{k p q} \sum_{l m n o} V_{l m n o, k p q} \epsilon_{l, k + p - q}^\dagger \epsilon_{m, q}^\dagger \epsilon_{n, p} \epsilon_{o, q}
$$
where
$$
\epsilon_k = \begin{pmatrix} d_k \\ u_k \end{pmatrix}
$$
is a vector of two different flavours of magnon annihilation operator (it's conjugate is analogously the creation operators) in the basis that diagonalises the quadratic portion of the Hamiltonian, $V_{k p q}$ is some tensor that depends on the momentums $k$, $p$, and $q$, and $l$, $m$, $n$, and $o$ loop over the indices of each vector. All in all my Hamiltonian is almost identical to the one in the paper, except for the form of $V$.

What I'm struggling to understand is the exact form of the equations that each diagram represents. In particular:

Regarding the rainbow diagram (second in fig 1d): I understand how the momentum works out, because $V$ is a function of three different momentums and one is taken as an input then the integral is over the other two, but I don't understand what they mean by the determinant of $V$ (or if $|V|$ doesn't refer to the determinant then I don't understand what it does refer to). Here $V$ is a fourth order tensor, but as far as I'm aware the determinant is only defined for matrices. My first thought was to expand out the sum over $l$, $m$, $n$, and $o$ and treat each term as a separate perturbation (i.e. one perturbation for $(l, m, n, o) = (1, 1, 1, 1)$, a second perturbation for $(1, 1, 1, 2)$, etc.) but I wasn't sure if that was correct or not (I guess if this is what they're doing then $|V|$ would just be the absolute value of $V$). Furthermore, that ends up being nine (in my case) separate integrals so I was wondering if there was a cleaner and more efficient way to do it.

Regarding the Hartree diagram (first in fig 1d): I realise that they handle this diagram in a different way (by replacing pairs of operators with BE distributions) but I was wondering if it were possible to handle this in the normal way? In particular what do you do with q since you're only integrating over p? Do you just set $q = p$? This makes sense to me in a handwavey conservation of momentum argument, but that doesn't mean it's actually correct.